# Class cast exception when extending ListActivity

Tags: java, android, android-listview

I am wondering why I am getting the following logcat when I run my app and try and click on the Daily Forecast option.

```
  Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.RelativeLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.ListView
```

HERE IS MY DAILYFORECASTACTIVITY

```
package com.dredaydesigns.stormy.ui;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Parcelable;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.dredaydesigns.stormy.R;
import com.dredaydesigns.stormy.adapters.DayAdapter;
import com.dredaydesigns.stormy.weather.Day;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class DailyForecastActivity extends ListActivity {

    private Day[] mDays;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_daily_forecast);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        Parcelable[] parcelables = intent.getParcelableArrayExtra(MainActivity.DAILY_FORECAST);
        mDays = Arrays.copyOf(parcelables, parcelables.length, Day[].class);
        DayAdapter adapter = new DayAdapter(this, mDays);

    }


    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

        String dayOfTheWeek = mDays[position].getDayOfTheWeek();
        String conditions = mDays[position].getSummary();
        String highTemp = mDays[position].getTemperatureMax()  + "";
        String message = String.format("On %s the high will be %s and it will be %s", dayOfTheWeek, highTemp, conditions);
        Toast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

EDIT: SORRY FORGOT TO POST THIS!HERE IS ACTIVITY DAILY FORECAST

```
'package com.dredaydesigns.stormy.ui;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Parcelable;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.dredaydesigns.stormy.R;
import com.dredaydesigns.stormy.adapters.DayAdapter;
import com.dredaydesigns.stormy.weather.Day;

import java.util.Arrays;

import butterknife.ButterKnife;

public class DailyForecastActivity extends ListActivity {

    private Day[] mDays;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_daily_forecast);
        ButterKnife.inject(this);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        Parcelable[] parcelables = intent.getParcelableArrayExtra(MainActivity.DAILY_FORECAST);
        mDays = Arrays.copyOf(parcelables, parcelables.length, Day[].class);
        DayAdapter adapter = new DayAdapter(this, mDays);

    }


    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

        String dayOfTheWeek = mDays[position].getDayOfTheWeek();
        String conditions = mDays[position].getSummary();
        String highTemp = mDays[position].getTemperatureMax()  + "";
        String message = String.format("On %s the high will be %s and it will be %s", dayOfTheWeek, highTemp, conditions);
        Toast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
'
```

Do I need to declare the ListActivity differently?

Comment: You need to post your `activity_daily_forecast` as well. So we can at least try to see what's wrong.

Comment: And please look at the similar questions and answers : [java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.RelativeLayout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20210679/java-lang-classcastexception-android-widget-relativelayout) , [Android listview trouble](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20547333/android-listview-trouble)

Comment: Ive looked at several and still cannot get it smh

Answer (score 0):

Set the id of your `ListView` id as `@android:id/list` and then your `onCreate` method will be

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_daily_forecast);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        Parcelable[] parcelables = intent.getParcelableArrayExtra(MainActivity.DAILY_FORECAST);
        mDays = Arrays.copyOf(parcelables, parcelables.length, Day[].class);
        DayAdapter adapter = new DayAdapter(this, mDays);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

Comment: it is currently set as @android:id/list but I did try and implement your onCreate method and got this error i belive the same.

 java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.RelativeLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.ListView
       ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
 ...
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException:

Comment: have you setted the adapter?

Comment: i dont know what that means :(